# MySQL Preference Pane control for MySQL installed via Homebrew

Tags: mysql, homebrew, system-preferences

*this is a repost of my question at [apple.stackexchange.com](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/13823/mysql-preference-pane-control-for-mysql-installed-via-homebrew)*

I have installed MySQL via [homebrew](https://brew.sh/): `brew install mysql`. I'd like to get the MySQL preference pane hooked up to my installation of MySQL through homebrew. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 10):

I've had the same issue. After googling my butt off, here's what I was able to find out:

1. install symlinks to Homebrew's MySQL installation in `/usr/local/mysql`:

   ```
   mkdir -p /usr/local/mysql; cd /usr/local/mysql
   ln -s $(brew --prefix mysql)/* .
   ```

   (this already allows you to *stop* the MySQL Server using the button in that [preference pane](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/macosx-installation-prefpane.html) – because it simply uses the `mysqladmin` binary – but not to *start* it)
2. The preference pane attempts to start the MySQL server **as user `mysql` or `_mysql`** rather than running it with *your* user name. They say it's a good idea to have a dedicated UNIX user for the SQL server anyway... Therefore the *data directory* must be owned by the user called `_mysql` or `mysql` as well.

   You can find out where your data directory is by looking for the entry `datadir=` inside `/etc/my.cnf`, or `$HOME/.my.cnf`, or `$(brew --prefix mysql)/support-files/mysql.server`, then [`chown`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/darwin/reference/manpages/man2/chown.2.html) it accordingly.

   Alternatively, you could start with a fresh data directory using [`mysql_install_db`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-install-db.html):

   ```
   unset TMPDIR
   sudo mysql_install_db --user=_mysql --basedir="$(brew --prefix mysql)" --datadir=/your/data/dir
   ```

   Note that, after installing it like this, you won't be able to start the MySQL server with **your** username anymore, at least not without `sudo -u`.

   If there's no user and/or group called `_mysql` on your system, you can create them using the `dscl` command line utility, as described [here](http://www.isi.edu/~voeckler/braindump/macosx-user-group-cli.html).
3. To start MySQL server automatically on system start, you'll need to
   install the [MySQL Startup Item](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/macosx-installation-startupitem.html), then activate the checkbox in
   the preference pane, and if you followed steps 1 and 2, on next reboot,
   it should work like a charm!

Comment: At first I can't use the start/stop button, then I uninstall the prefPane, redo all the step abover, then install the prefPane and it works. Thanks!